# If arbitrary wavefunctions can be expanded as energy eigenfunctions of a schodinger equation, is it mean that it can solve schodinger equation anyway?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, superposition

We know that the superpostion of solutions also sloves the schodinger eq, and any wavefunction can be expended as superposition of energy eigenstates. Is it means that any wavefunction can solve the  schodinger eq? That sounds weird.

The question actually comes from the MIT8.06 lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnZR0TVNh2k&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60QlYNsy52fctVBOlk-4lYx&index=3 (1:02:46), where the professor stated that the trial wave function is not the solution of schodinger eq, but can be expended as energy eigenstates, so I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

This means that any function that respects the boundary conditions of the solutions of the Schroedinger equation indeed solves the Schroedinger equation, yes. But beware, as this restriction is powerful and remember that you have to solve the Schroedinger equation somewhere :)

If there are any questions, please do not hesitate to comment..

Comment: Thanks! This question actually comes from the MIT8.06 lecture https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lnZR0TVNh2k&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60QlYNsy52fctVBOlk-4lYx&index=3 (1:02:46), where the professor state that the trial wave function is not the solution of schodinger eq, but can be expended as energy eigenstates, so I'm confused.

Comment: You are welcome. I am saying this because for the expansion to take place, the function to be expanded needs to also satisfy the boundary conditions!