# In what way are eigenfunctions of an observable operator complete?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am a physics undergraduate reading through Griffiths's 2ed Quantum book.

In section 3.4 (Generalized Statistical Interpretation), Griffiths states:

> The eigenfunctions of an observable operator are *complete*, so the wave function can be written as a linear combination of them: $$ \Psi(x,t) = \Sigma_nc_nf_n(x). $$

1. The eigenfunctions of an observable operator are complete over what interval? Griffiths states earlier that this completeness allows any function in Hilbert space to be written as a linear combination of said eigenfunctions. Can't functions dependent on arbitrary and random vectors live in the Hilbert space? How can this statement of Griffiths be true?
2. What does "the wave function" refer to? Does it refer to any wave function possible? This is a section on generalizing, after all.
3. If it does refer to any wave function possible, how can an arbitrary function of time and position be written as a linear combination of a complete set of functions of position only (and not a complete set of functions over an interval of time)?

I know that Griffiths mentions that $c_n$ is dependent on time. But I expect that an arbitrary function of time and position can be written as a sum of two functions: one function of position complete over the respective interval and another function of time complete over the respective interval (e.g. like how we expand electric potential in spherical coordinates). Here, we don't know what $c_n$ really is, I think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the completeness and linearity of Schrodinger equation's solution, can we say that any wavefunction can solve any Schrodinger equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/719652/)

Answer (score 0):

Here, "wave function" refers to any possible wave function for the system. A wave function that is invalid for the system for which you found those eigenfunctions $f$ cannot, in general, be expressed as a superposition of the eigenfunctions. For instance, if you are considering a square well in one dimension in the coordinates $[0,a]$, with $f_n$ corresponding to the $n$th energy eigenfunction, and $\Psi(x,t_0)=\delta(a+1)$, you cannot express $\Psi$ in such a superposition. Griffiths clarifies that this is his intention in the lead-up to the quoted phrase, when he argues that the particle is "in" the state $\Psi$, and the observable is $Q(x,p)$. Of course, there exist observables whose operators are the same for all systems (within reason), including position, momentum, and angular momentum. If the eigenfunctions in question are of one of these operators, they form a basis for an arbitrary wave function $\Psi$, but Griffiths does not refer to these cases.

I'm not sure which version of the book you are using, but if that is a direct quote, there is a typo, and the equation should include $c_n(t)$. You are correct that a time-independent RHS is not in general equal to an LHS with nontrivial time dependence. For the case of energy eigenfunctions, $c_n(t)$ will take the simple form of a number multiplied by an oscillating complex phase, but for eigenfunctions of another observable, the time dependence of $c_n$ can be quite intricate. It is not true that an arbitrary function of time and position can be written as a sum of a function of position and a function of time.